# Angular ts datepipe error "invalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "03:45:00" into a date'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm want to show a Date object that i get through an API on the frontend as a 'shortTime' so only the hours and the minutes.

But when I do that through:

```
<h2>{{data.scheduleTime | date:'shortTime'}} - {{data.actualLandingTime | date:'shortTime'}}</h2><br>
```

I get the following error:
InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "03:45:00" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

And I think that's because Angular doesn't think the object is of type Date...

I receive those objects through a API call in JSON format. I've made a model to set the types of the object. Both "scheduleTime" and "actualLandingTime" are date objects in de model:

My model calles FlightInfoModel:

```
actualLandingTime:           Date;
scheduleTime:                Date;
```

I receive them as:

```
actualLandingTime: "2020-04-29T03:17:33.000+02:00"
scheduleTime: "03:45:00"
```

for both I only want to display the hours and minutes..

If it helps to see the problem this is how I get the API for that page:

```
data: FlightInfoModel;

  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.flightService.getFligthInfo<any>('129392719696922308').subscribe(response => {this.data = response, console.log(response)},
        error => console.log(error));


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you are receiving for scheduleTime is not valid date format since it only includes the time. One somewhat hacky solution would be to create a new Date object with an arbitrary year, month, and day and the time from the string you are getting.

```
let scheduleDate = new Date(2020, 4, 4, ...scheduleTime.split(':').map(t => Number(t));
```

This will pass the hour, minute, and second of that time string in to the Date constructor.

You could do something like the above code in a map step (i.e pipe your observable response to the rxjs map operator). You might also want to change the type of scheduleTime to `Date | string` and do the conversion whenever it is an instance of string rather than Date.

Here is a complete code sample:

```
this.flightService.getFligthInfo<any>('129392719696922308').pipe(
  map(info => {
    if(typeof info.scheduleTime === "string") {
       const splitTime: number[] = (<string>info.scheduleTime)
         .split(':')
         .map(t => Number(t));
       return {
         actualLandingTime: info.actualLandingTime,
         scheduleTime: new Date(2020, 4, 4, ...splitTime)
       }
    }
    return info
  }
)
```

Don't forget to import map from `rxjs/operators`

When you pass this through the date pipe it will accept it as a valid Date.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution! but when I add the above in my code I get an error at ...splitTime. The error says: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Comment: I added a map after split to explicitly convert the strings in the array to type number and also set the type of splitTime to number[]. I tested this and it worked for me